# SwingX - personalize JXDatePicker

Tags: java, swing, swingx

I want to personalize the JXDatePicker. More specifically I want to create an own own action button on a an own position. I tried to extract the included JButton but when I try to add it to any JPanel it only adds empty space.

```
JXDatePicker fDate = new JXDatePicker(new Date());
fDate.getEditor().setBorder(null);
fDate.getEditor().setEditable(false);
JButton eDate = (JButton) fDate.getComponent(1);
fDate.remove(eDate);
```

I don't think this approach would work anyway, but I don't know any better at the moment. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm...can you extend `JXDatePicker`? Or perhaps you can pull it's guts out with a call to `getContentPane()` or some similar method? Really, the answer might just be that you can't.

Comment: why? Okay, okay, it's not looking overly nice, I know :-) It's not supported, to change you'll have to write your own DatePickerUI - have a look at the Basic* implementation for ideas

Comment: @kleopatra yes the look don't matches my other components :) Where can I find the basic implementation?  I tried to understand the sourcecode of the JXDatePicker but couldn't find anything about the button http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Swing-Library/swingx/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXDatePicker.java.htm

Comment: look at the source of BasicDatePickerUI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found a working solution, migt be not the cleanest way:

```
JXDatePicker fDate = new JXDatePicker(new Date());

//edit the Textfield
fDate.getEditor().setBorder(null);
fDate.getEditor().setEditable(false);

//edit the Button
JButton dateBtn= (JButton) fDate.getComponent(1);
Image editImage  =Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/toolbarButtonGraphics/general/Edit16.gif"));

dateBtn.remove(eDate);  
dateBtn.setIcon(new ImageIcon(editImage));
dateBtn.setFocusPainted(false);
dateBtn.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
dateBtn.setContentAreaFilled(false);
dateBtn.setBorderPainted(false);
dateBtn.setOpaque(false);
```

I added the dateBtn somewhere else in my view.

Answer (score 1):

```
((JButton) startDatePicker.getComponent(1)).setIcon(new ImageIcon(((new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/calendar.png"))).getImage()).getScaledInstance(20, 20, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
```